# How can I retrieve the ID primary key value following a SQL Server CE Insert?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, azure-mobile-services

I want to store data locally in a SQL Server CE table AND in the cloud (WAMS or ZUMO table).

I have a `storedInCloud` bool column in the SQL Server CE table that is first set to false, and then, when the insert to the cloud table succeeds, is updated to true. That way I can continue to attempt to "seed the cloud" until successful.

To do this, though, I want the primary ID key from the SQL Server CE table* so I know which table to update. My desired pseudocode is:

```
int locID = App.TaSLs_SQLCE_LocationDataContext._taSLs_SQLCE_Location.InsertOnSubmit(newLocation);
locDB.SubmitChanges();
if (InsertRecordToCloud(newLocation))
{
    //Update SQL Server CE table, setting storedInCloud to true for record where LocationID = locID
}
```

...but this won't work because SQL Server CE's `InsertOnSubmit` doesn't actually insert the record, so no `ID` val is generated. `SubmitChanges()` does insert, but it could be multiple records/changes that are submitted.

So is there a way to, in effect, loop through and submit one change at a time, getting back the primary key val (`LocationID`, below)?

```
*[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int LocationId
    . . .
```

On second thought, I guess I could reverse the order of the table commits/submits, so that I could do this:

```
if (CommitToCloudSucceeds)
{
    // insert into SQL Server CE, setting storedInCloud to true
}
else
{
    // insert into SQL Server CE, setting storedInCloud to false
}
```

...and then periodically loop through the SQL Server CE table, calling the above code for those records where `storedInCloud = false`.